# How can I combine express and react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting an error with the twitter npm module when I run my react project using webpack with webpack-dev-server.

The error is:

```
*ERROR in ./~/twitter/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/timings.json
Module parse failed: /Users/peterkaminski/react-test/node_modules/twitter/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/timings.json Unexpected token (2:12)*
```

And I'm only getting it when I require twitter. My current project setup uses webpack and babel.

A solution I've tried coming up with is to just set up an express server to handle all my API calls while I render all the frontend with React. I've tried finding several tutorials for how to incorporate express with React, but *none of them have been very clear*.

What's the best way to set up a project so you can include various node modules without getting these kinds of errors, and how do you go about running React with Express?

Comment: Sounds like you're not `exclude`ing `node_modules` from your Webpack loader configuration.

Comment: You might be confusing some terms here - express is an http server, it responds to HTTP verbs and that's pretty much its only job, whereas React is a user-facing UI library that runs in the browser. The only time those "work together" is if you're doing server-side page rendering so that there's already "a static page" that the user sees before React actually kicks in and replaces it with the real interactive UI. That's not to say you don't have a question, but you may want to rephrase it a little.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your loader including node_modules and the library you are using have a JSON file which webpack is not able to bundle because you are missing json-loader
Install json-loader with `npm install json-loader` and configure your webpack to handle json files.

> By the way you should exclude node_modules if you don't need to bundle
>   it.

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you

Comment: I'm getting these errors now: 

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in...

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net'...
ERROR in ./~/twitter/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/peterkaminski/react-test/node_modules/twitter/node_modules/request/node_modules/forever-agent
 @ ./~/twitter/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24

Comment: ^ After npm install --save json-loader
and making my loader look like this: 
loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" }
    ]

Comment: I should also point out that I tried { test: /\.json$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "json-loader" } and that didn't work either.

Comment: And now this is comment. Your original error regarding parsing json is gone, it is something else so update your question so someone else also can understand what is going on and how to help you. This was right approach { test: /\.json$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "json-loader" }

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example set up that allows you to get to developing (npm package and webpack included )

1. package.json

   ```
   {
     "name": "mvp",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "nodemon server/server.js",
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "webpack": "webpack --watch"
     },

     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "dependencies": {
       "angular": "^1.6.4",
       "axios": "^0.16.2",
       "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
       "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
       "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
       "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
       "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
       "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
       "cors": "^2.8.3",
       "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
       "express": "^4.15.3",
       "lodash": "^4.17.4",
       "morgan": "^1.8.2",
       "pg": "^6.2.4",
       "react": "^15.6.0",
       "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
       "react-dom": "^15.6.0",
       "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
       "reactstrap": "^4.6.2",
       "sequelize": "^4.0.0",
       "webpack": "^2.6.1"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
     }
   }
   ```
2. webpack.config

   ```
   //this is a code 
   const path = require('path');

   const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'react-client/src');
   const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'react-client');

   module.exports = {
     entry: path.resolve(SRC_DIR, 'index.js'),
     output: {
       filename: 'bundle.js',
       path: BUILD_DIR
     },
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
           exclude: [/node_modules/],
           use: [{
             loader: 'babel-loader',
             options: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
           }],
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. example server.js setup

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   const morgan = require('morgan')
   const port = 8000
   const db = require('../database/config.js')
   const todoListRouter = require('./router/todoList.router')
   const cors = require('cors')
   const app = express()

   app.use(express.static('react-client'))
      .use(bodyParser.json())
      .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
      .use(morgan('dev'))
      .use('/api', todoListRouter)

   app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "x")
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Request-With");
       next();
   })

   app.listen(port, 'localhost', ()=>{
       console.log("server running on port :" + port);
   })
   ```
4. given your react index.js, this is an example of importing what you need

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
   import axios from 'axios'
   import NavBar from '../src/components/navbar'
   import ToDo from '../src/components/todo'
   import ToDoBuilder from '../src/components/todobuilder'
   import ToDoList from '../src/components/todolist'
   import ToDosWithSameUser from '../src/components/todowithsameuser'
   ....//your component here
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
   ```

in short, look at the entry point in webpack.config.js, you can see that it looks at 'react-client/src' and find index.js.

to run the script, simply do 
npm start, 
npm run webpack